# Is it required that scss file convert to css

Tags: javascript, angular, scss-lint

When I use scss as default style in my angular project. Without compiling the .scss file to .css, style is applied.therefore I want to know that the scss is directly applicable in project without compiling to css.I use vs code editor .

Comment: Some classes may be useable if they are valid CSS, but any variable expansion or nesting must be performed either by the compilation or with a javascript library.  The browser will ignore anything that isn't parseable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Browsers don't natively support scss**. 
 *But* [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/) projects have scripts that compile your scss into css and bundle these files using [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/). You will get the scripts *by default* with Angular CLI.

**Solution** 
 You only need to run `ng serve` in Angular CLI to have Webpack compile, bundle, and serve your files.